# Calculating the lifting force $F_{Kab}$ with SolidWorks – according to VDI 2230

Tags: solidworks, bolting, threads

I’m not sure if my procedure to simulate the lifting force $F_{Kab}$ is correct. So I illustrate my way how to get the lifting force $F_{Kab}$ using SolidWorks and the simulation tool.

I hope you can give me a hint how to solve my issue correctly or perhaps you can also confirm my procedure. Many thanks in advance.

**My procedure:**

According to VDI 2230 I have to do two variants of calculation:

- applying the minimum assembly preload (see step of calculation R1)

  - in R0 I get $F_{Mmax}$ using the table A7

    - table A7 you can find via a google search. Enter "vdi 2230 pdf" and I think then you get a pdf and look for table A7 (see annex).
  - with $\alpha_A$ the tightening factor I get the $F_{Mmin,variant1}=F_{Mmax}/\alpha_A$ which is applied to every bolt
- applying the maximum reduction in preloading force (see step of calculation R4)

  - here my $F_{Mmin,variant2}=F_{Mmin,variant1}-F_z$ which is also applied to every bolt
  - $F_z$ is the loss of preload as a result of embedding during operation

In the simulation all possible loads are active and are acting on the housing. The bolts are tighten in the first simulation with $F_{Mmin,variant1}$ and in the second simulation with $F_{Mmin,variant2}$.

Perform the two simulations…

To get the lifting force $F_{Kab}$ I right click the simulation results and pick “list result forces”. And now I choose “free body force”, klick the appropriate housing surface and klick the update-button. Now SolidWorks shows me the (total) lifting force $F_{Kab}$. This force divided by quantity of bolts gives me the $F_{Kab}$ per bolt which I’m interested in.

For my further calculations according to VDI 2230 I have to take the smallest $F_{Kab}$ per bolt.

Comment: This question seems to be missing a diagram?

Comment: @ Jonathan R Swift: Not really... I could only offer some screenshots. But therefore I have described (my) SolidWorks workflow very detailed. But when its not clear, then I will complete the SolidWorks description. And when you mean table A7 - I'm not sure if I can copy it (copyright).